# How to embed a Google Map?

Tags: html, embedding, getmap

Is there a way to embed the HTML code that Google Maps provide to embed your map in your pdf using LaTeX?

The source HTML code looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3036.4313574576963!2d-79.9457446846033!3d40.44358877936194!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8834f2219059e091%3A0x47888be8ae0bea3a!2s5000+Forbes+Ave%2C+Pittsburgh%2C+PA+15213!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1445448752174" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: what do you want to happen if you put html in a pdf file?

Comment: PNGs served by Google **Static** Maps API can be displayed in `SlideShow.swf` (package `media9`).

Comment: PDFs with dynamic content are critical in the sense that it will very probably lead to problems for many possible users.  Depending on your application, maybe it is easier to convert the rest of your document to HTML?  Another possibility would be to have a screenshot as well as a link to google maps.  Links are very easy to generate using the packages `hyperref` and `url`.

Comment: May be you can try with getmap package. Some how I don't understand those keys used. So can't help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [getmap](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/getmap) package. It offers an interface to Google Maps' Static Image API!

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[overwrite=true,mode=gm]{getmap}
\begin{document}
\getmap[file=pittsburgh,
        color=blue,
        number=A,
        xsize=600,
        ysize=450,
        zoom=16,
        scale=2]
       {Forbes Ave, Pittsburgh, USA}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{pittsburgh}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`getmap` needs the `\write18` feature enabled, therefore you must compile the file with the `-shell-escape` switch, e.g.:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape testfile
```

`getmap` offers much more incl. interfaces to Open Street Map and Google Streetview.

For details take a look into `getmap`'s documentation (`texdoc getmap`) or its [wiki](http://kirza.kleberj.de/bbgetmap)!

Comment: This looks nice.  Do you know if there is a package that does the same thing, but includes the dynamic zoom option?  I want to do something like embedding the map in the PDF as they do on some sites to note the address of a certain place

Answer (score -2):

You should screenshot the map and embed it as a png.  This answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867641/pdf-dynamic-content-is-it-possible  talks about dynamic content in a pdf.  It will not work on every pdf viewer.

Comment: This is a rather a comment ;-)